# How do I get going with Bokeh? Seeing errors in running simple code

Tags: error-handling, pycharm, bokeh

I am trying to get started on bokeh via pycharm. I have installed Bokeh by entering "pip install bokeh" in the cmd prompt and get a message saying it has been installed successfully. After this, I have also gone onto setting and installed "bokeh" as a new package under 'project interpreter'.

After this I am trying to run the simple code in the bokeh quick start guide, using bokeh.plotting and output_file expecting a browser to open up with the output. However, this is where I get into a pickle, and see a few error messages. Not exactly sure where I am going wrong.

I am very new to this and would appreciate any help possible!

[image: Message after installation]

[image: Error message]

[image: Code Being used]

[image: When I enter [bokeh info] in same environment as the code]

Comment: What does `bokeh.__version__` output?

Comment: Where do I type bokeh._version_?

Comment: Just run `bokeh info` in the same environment that you used to run the above code.

Comment: Hi Eugene, i've added a pic to show you what pops up when type [bokeh info] into the same area where the above code is. Not sure if i've gone wrong with the installation somewhere? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I  said "run", not "write". :) Run it as you run `python -m ...`, all that stuff. Just type `bokeh info` into your CMD window and hit Enter.

Comment: Manage to make it work now! Thank you